# giving a css path to html but it is not working

Tags: html, css

```
<link  rel="stylesheet"  href="index.css" >  
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="index.css" >
<link  rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css"  href="index.css" media="screen" >
```

tried all of them but it's not working

Comment: The path of the file should be correct, for Ex. here is the bootstrap cdn: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

Answer (score 0):

try using a different name for the stylesheet rather than 'index.css' go for 'style.css' as everybody does.
Make Sure the CSS File is located in the same directory as the index.html and change the reference link to

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

or

```
<link href="./style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the path to your file you can try,

```
<link href="./style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

This should work if your file is in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

The path mentioned in the above example does not have a full URL or relative path that begins with "**/**".

This makes the browser think that the **css** file is at the same level as that of the **html** file. Therefore, it may fail to fetch the file correctly.

**Updating the path of the css file** to either a ***full URL*** or to a ***relative path***  will solve the problem.

Example:

Suppose that the website is organized into the following folder structure:

```
/index.html


/css/index.css
/css/main.css

/js/header.js
/js/footer.js
...

/images/hero.jpg
/images/logo.png
...


The call to the css file will work if the link is defined like this, in index.html:

<link  rel="stylesheet"  href="/css/index.css" >
```